# Audio on both bluetooth headset and onboard speakers simultaneously?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, streaming, bluetooth-audio, nvidia-shield

I'm attempting to use a Bluetooth pair of headphones on my Nvidia Shield Tablet, but I'd also like the on-board speakers to remain on so I can stream that audio to my PC to broadcast on the internet. Any ideas on how I can get both the Bluetooth headphones and on-board speakers working at the same time?

Comment: This [StackOverflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210696/simultaneously-using-a-headphone-and-speaker/14211450#14211450) provides some insight into why this is hard.